# A possible complete metric on the set of twice-differentiable functions on $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

> Let $S \subset C^2[0,1]$ (set of two times differentiable functions $f(x)$ on $[0,1]$) which satisfy the following: $$\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx\leq3$$
>   Question is $(S,d)$ is a complete metric space, where $$d(f,g)=\sup_{x \in [0,1]}|f(x)-g(x)|+ \sup_{x \in [0,1]}|f'(x)-g'(x)| + \sup_{x \in [0,1]}|f''(x)-g''(x)|.$$

I am somewhat sure that I can prove that $d$ is a metric indeed. The rest, a complete mystery. I will almost definitely attach a boundy to this question.

Comment: Note that the (completeness) tag was deemed to have no real value. See the meta discussion [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/21031).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** note that $C^2[0,1]$ is a complete space under the metric $d$.  So, it suffices to show that if we have a sequence of functions $\{f_n\} \subset S$ with $f_n \to f$ in $C^2[0,1]$, then $f \in S$. That is, it suffices to prove the following result:

> Suppose that $\{f_n\} \subset C^2[0,1]$ satisfies $\lim_{n \to \infty}d(f_n,f) = 0$ and that for each $n$, we have
>    $$
> \int_0^1 f_n(x)\,dx \leq 3
>  $$
>   Then $f$ satisfies $\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx \leq 3$.